# NLP - Morphological Dictionary for English

Tags: c++, python, xml-parsing, nlp

I need to be able to morphologically generate a word according to its lemma and a POS Tag value. For instance change a lemma verb form to its past tense, present or change a lemma noun to its plural form...
For that I need a Morphological Dictionary for English that will include a mapping from a lemma to the word with the type requested (plural, past tense etc...).
Does anyone know of a good Morphological Dictionary for English available for download?

Thanks a lot,
Yaron

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [NodeBox library](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics)?